# Need to re-specify parameter types of class methods that implement interface methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

The Calculator class is implemented from ICalculator, where all methods and their types are described, is it worth doing this again for class methods parameters? If I remove, then any data  type can be passed to the method. Please tell me how to write correctly, i just started to learn TypeScript

```js
interface ICalculator {
    add(num: number): number;
    subtract(num: number): number;
    multiply(num: number): number;
    divide(num: number): number;
    print(): void;
}

class Calculator implements ICalculator {
    protected _res: number = 0;

    add(num: number) {
        return this._res = num + this._res;
    }

    subtract(num: number) {
        return this._res = this._res - num;
    }

    multiply(num: number) {
        return this._res = num * this._res;
    }

    divide(num: number) {
        return this._res = this._res / num;
    }

    print(): void {
        console.log(`Currently value: ${this._res}`);
    }
}
let myCalc = new Calculator();

myCalc.add(260);
myCalc.subtract(12);
myCalc.multiply(12);
myCalc.divide(2);
myCalc.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you currently have to write the parameter types again.  Here is [the open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).  You can enable the `noImplicitAny` compiler option to check that you haven't missed any type annotations.